# md-card and ng-click gives annoying blue border

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Trying to figure out how to get rid of annoying highlight when using ng-click on a md-card. Basically, all I did was set up a md-card and add a nd-click to it.

```
<md-card ng-click="showart(sketch.id)" class="magazinecard">
        <md-card-header>
        <md-card-header-text>
        <span class="md-headline">{{sketch.name}}</span>
        <span class="md-subhead">By user: {{sketch.owner}} data: </span>
        </md-card-header-text>
        </md-card-header>
        <img data-ng-src="data:{{image.type}};base64,{{image.data}}"/>
        <md-card-content style="background-color: white; color: black;"><div style="width: 325px;" ng-bind-html="sketch.description"></div></md-card-content>
        <md-card-content layout="row" layout-align="space-between">
        <md-card-actions layout="row">
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Favorite">
        <ng-md-icon size="20px" icon="favorite"></ng-md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Share">
        <ng-md-icon size="20px" icon="share"></ng-md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings">
        <ng-md-icon size="20px" icon="delete"></ng-md-icon>
        </md-button>
        </md-card-actions>
        </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
```

As soon as I click on the md-card, I get a blue line around the whole card, and I can't figure out how to control it. 
Tried changing md-card:focus and .md-card:focus, but nothing

```
.md-card:focus {
  border-color: #7b007b;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for `outline:none` and `border: 0`. Just add it to your css selector like so:

```
.md-card:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
 }
```

I'm not sure it's the `.md-card` necessarily, because I can't see it running but that blue border is from a `:focus`.

Comment: It was't .md-card, in my cases I ended up using md-card:focus to limit the impact, but just doing :focus worked as well

Comment: @vrghost you can do something universal like *:focus, but it's generally better to target specifically. Glad it worked :).

Comment: Worked a charm, also missed clicking accept on you solution, an oversight I have now corrected:)